# Using Github Repository metadata with Jekyll & Javascript

Tags: javascript, github, repository, metadata, jekyll

I have been following the article [Github Metadata with Jekyll and JavaScript](http://www.carsonshold.com/2014/05/github-metadata-with-jekyll-and-javascript/) which mentions how to use Github Repository Metadata using Jekyll and Javascript.

The article there says that you need to add the following to **index.html** before the link to an external JS file. Now repos is globally available so you can use it in our external JS file.

```
<script>
  var repos = {{ site.github.public_repositories | jsonify }};
</script>
```

I have created an **index.html** file which contains the following contents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>GitHub Repository</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  var repos = {{ site.github.public_repositories | jsonify }};
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="github-repo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**github-repo.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(repos);
});
```

But, when I run the code I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: repos is not defined** error

Comment: What is the environment you run the code in?